# Does the past participle always imply that an object was, at some point, not in its current state?

Tags: nuance

When someone says

> This is a dried handkerchief

It is usually implying that, at one point, the handkerchief was not dry.

However, does this apply to all past participles?

If I say :

> I would like a medium-sized burger

Does that imply I want a burger that was previously a different size made into a medium size?

Comment: Where's the pp in "I would like a medium-sized burger" ?

Comment: I'm afraid *sized* in *medium-sized* is not a verb at all.

Comment: Isn't sized the past participle of size?

Comment: -sized *adj.* = having a specified size

Comment: So some words are adjectives even though they look like past participles? Okay, what about "located?" If I say that something is located somewhere, does that imply at some point it wasn't there?

Comment: "If I say that something is located somewhere, does that imply at some point it wasn't there?" Nope. Same as above.

Comment: "This is a dried handkerchief" could be passive in meaning; it was wet, but someone dried it. We don't know who or what dried the handkerchief.On the other hand, dried is also an adjective, and a "dried towel" tells us that the towel that was wet, is now *dry*. Compare: "I dried my hair before leaving the house" and "Although my [air-dried hair](https://www.google.it/search?q=air-dried+hair&oq=air-dried+hair&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22air-dried%22+hair) felt soft to the touch, it looked a real mess."

Comment: "medium-sized" is a compound, it is not a verb. "He medium-sized his trousers" is not grammatical.

Comment: Where **is** the hotel located? (present simple tense)

Comment: For *salted nuts*, the salt is added to unsalted nuts, but for *salted caramel*, the salt is added when the caramel is being made, so it was never unsalted. Is *salted* a past participle in one of these expressions and an adjective in the other?

Comment: Participial adjectives from stative verbs don't necessarily signify a change. 'Needed qualities' just means 'necessary qualities'. When a participle has undergone full conversion to a true adjective is a different question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, but in our infinite wisdom here in the US (tongue-in-cheek), you can "super-size" your meal at McDonalds to get a large French fries and large drink.  :-)

Comment: I'm thinking this question is more dependent on context than prior or present state.  The case of the dried handkerchief...you'd mention the state of dryness of the item if everything else was wet, such as in a rainstorm, and I'd call it a "dry handkerchief", not a dried one since it's prior state is not meaningful to the context.  What importance does the size of a previously ordered hamburger play when now ordering a medium-sized hamburger?  At some point, the question needs to make sense before addressing grammatical concepts and I don't think this one does - voting to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, some words are adjectives not derived from verbs even though they look like past participles.  The reason is that Old English bequeathed us two means to append the suffix *-ed* to make adjectives.  The one that you've noted forms the past participle of a verb.  The other converts a noun into an adjective to connote "*with*."  Thus a three-legg*ed* stool means one *with* three legs.
2. Verbs denote action (non-copoulative verbs, anyway), and actions start and stop, so it's no surprise that an adjectival participle can describe a state that is now but wasn't in the past.  But that's not always the case.  One of the most famous fictional narrators in American literature starts out by saying "Call me Ishmael."  So he is *named* Ishmael, and there's no reason to believe there was ever a time he wasn't.

Comment: Not all non-linking verbs denote action. Stative verbs exist (include (= comprise or contain as part of a whole) / possess / need ...).  A good counter-example is 'needed', where the participial adjective in no way implies a previous lack of need.

Answer (score 0):

See the **secondary** definitions for the suffix *-ed*:

[Dictionary com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/-ed)

> -ed<sup>2</sup>
>   1. a suffix forming the past participle of weak verbs (*he had crossed the river*), and of **participial adjectives indicating a condition or quality resulting from the action of the verb** (*inflated balloons*).
>   Origin
>   Old English *-ed*, *-od*, *-ad*; orig. disputed
>   
>   -ed<sup>3</sup>
>   1. a suffix **forming adjectives from nouns**:
>   *bearded*; *monied*; *tender-hearted*.
>   Origin
>   Middle English; Old English *-ede*
>   [emphasis added]

[MW Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-ed):

> 3
>   a:  having :  characterized by  
>   b :  having the characteristics of